# VSCode: Is it possible to have global search combined with search by filename (functionality of ctrl+shift+f & ctrl+p combined)

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, search, navigation, hotkeys

I would like to be able to search for file contents AS WELL AS to include files with matching path- and/or filenames in the results when using `ctrl+shift+f` global search.

So, basically, akin to `ctrl+shift+f` (global search) and `ctrl+p` (goto file) combined.

Is it possible or is there any extension out there to make it possible?